# Problem with YouTube Data Api PlaylistItems: list. Why video duplicates in pagination?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to get list of all videos in a playlist.
I am using request to the API https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems with parameters `part=contentDetails`, `maxResults=50`, `playlistId=***`, `pageToken=***`
But here is the problem: the same video appears on different pages on pagination.

I am trying to do this action several times but some videos always duplicates.
I even try to do all request in Postman step by step just if there is error in my code but result is the same.

Comment: If you don't share a playlist id having this bug on your end, we can't verify on our end, so we can't help you without it.

Comment: channelId = UCMXQ4DrGV46lpuJontzajYQ, playListId = UUMXQ4DrGV46lpuJontzajYQ

Comment: I am facing the same issue on playListId = UUfxXoooBuDXzhi6348dVfIw

Comment: playListId = UUnpqjEw2RHDBNVGDe8pI7tw I think the problem appears when the total count of items on playlist is greater than 1k elements. All channels has more than 1k elements. I was testing channels with less elements and there is no problem.

Comment: [I confirm that there isn't any problem on my end](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2454863) with the playlist id [`UUnpqjEw2RHDBNVGDe8pI7tw`](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUnpqjEw2RHDBNVGDe8pI7tw).

Comment: I am trying [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUMXQ4DrGV46lpuJontzajYQ) `UUMXQ4DrGV46lpuJontzajYQ`. Video with id `ZSeyPkG7CZw` appears on 603 position [link](https://snipboard.io/NBzxY7.jpg) `screenshot` and 703 position [link](https://snipboard.io/HX9MBy.jpg) `screenshot`

Comment: 1/4 [The playlist you shared was `Updated today` according to YouTube UI](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUMXQ4DrGV46lpuJontzajYQ). The video with id [`ZSeyPkG7CZw`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSeyPkG7CZw&list=UUMXQ4DrGV46lpuJontzajYQ&index=318) now appears at index 318.

Comment: 2/4 Note that the first *video link* you provided is showing [`KLg6GHhVDZw`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KLg6GHhVDZw), as you can read at the bottom left of your screenshot, same thing for the second *video link* it's showing [`ZSeyPkG7CZw`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSeyPkG7CZw), as you can read at the bottom left of your screenshot. I agree that the titles and thumbnails that I currently see aren't the same as on your screenshots. Weird thing that the source-code seems different than what is displayed at the bottom left.

Comment: 3/4 Indeed I currently see respectively [`Schneider Electric Asfora`](https://img.youtube.com/vi/KLg6GHhVDZw/maxresdefault.jpg) and [`Schneider Electric Sedna`](https://img.youtube.com/vi/ZSeyPkG7CZw/maxresdefault.jpg). Maybe YouTube UI is going wrong on your end, as the playlist was updated in the last 24 hours, or the channel modified the given videos, as the playlist author and the videos author is *the same person*. However I admit that as its an `uploads` playlist the channel doesn't have much ability to modify it as he wishes.

Comment: 4/4 Anyway nothing is really going wrong as [I verified thanks to my verification script the correctness of the latest playlist you sent](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2454978). In any case a YouTube channel can upload twice the same video with the same title and the same thumbnail, but these two videos will have different videos ids (as we see on your screenshots). Because it's the `uploads` playlist, we have the guarantee that every video in it will have different videos ids.

Comment: I believe this is the [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258237323) posted by the OP *original poster* on Issue tracker.

Comment: It is mine ticket)